# Standard deviation of interpolated data

Tags: interpolation, spatial-statistics, kriging, inverse-distance-weighted, surface

I have a dataset with air-quality measurements in several points across one state, through several months. Thus, for each point I can calculate average, variance and so. My goal is to interpolate data for all the state and identify the average AND variance for any given point. From what I understood, I can interpolate the average (using KRIGING?) and estimate the surface for all state.

- How can I estimate the variance surface? Does it make sense to create a second interpolation with the variance of each point?

Comment: Are you using any particular software?

Comment: @BERA I'm using Python, but I'm also confortable with R and QGIS